# Temperature and electrolysis

Tags: electrolysis, temperature, electrical-properties

Based on my understanding, metals conduct electricity better at lower temperatures than at higher temperatures as the resistance to electron flow is lower.

Then, what about ionic compounds? Do they conduct electricity better at higher temperatures? The electrical conductivity of ionic compounds is tested through the set-up of electrolysis. So I mean, is there a larger current flow in electrolysis when the aqueous solution/ molten liquid of ionic compounds is at higher temperatures?

Comment: I expect them to behave similar to metals and different from semiconductors.

Answer (score 1):

> Based on my understanding, metals conduct electricity better at lower temperatures than at higher temperatures as the resistance to electron flow is lower.

This statement is correct, the conductivity of a metal decreases with temperature, this is due to the collision rate, [the Drude model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drude_model) explains it very well.

> Then, what about ionic compounds? Do they conduct electricity better at higher temperatures?

The temperature increases a random velocity of ions and the electric field creates a drift velocity, the effects combined give a better conductivity. The ions can also be scattered, the rate depends on the size of the ions.